# aspnethidden CSS class missing in ASP webforms application

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

this might be simple, but I can't find information about it.

Why is the aspnethidden CSS class missing from the div's around hidden form fields in my development environment and not on the production environment? It looks like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="..." />
</div>
```

instead of this:

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="..." />
</div>
```

The server and my dev machine are running on .NET Framework 4.6.1 and IIS is configured to use the .NET CLR 4.0 in the application pool.

I'm just curious to know why this is missing on my Windows 10 Dev machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one which you are observing is a New feature .It is about the hidden fields in ASP.Net 4.0.

You probably might aware that  ASP.Net is using hidden fields as a state control mechanism. It is used to preserve `Viewstate` and `Control state`.

They are usually included in a `div` element, `<div></div>`.

I have created a sample asp.net application in **VS2010** and **.Net 3.5**

when i see my view source i'm able to see something like this

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/rxyklmnLTQ0NTA1Mstupvmjk8I5q9vNjFXLeK/1IBsUwBM=" />
</div>
```

when you apply any css rules for div elements in your external css file, those rules that apply for all div elements in your code, will apply for that `<div>` that surrounds the hidden field elements that dealing with the viewstate.

When you create the application with the **Asp.net 4.0** will render with `CSS` class around `div`

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />
</div>
```

Based on My Research here are some Souces which will elaborate more

1. [how-to-handle-the-div-tag-around-asp.net-hidden-inputs.aspx](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/15/how-to-handle-the-div-tag-around-asp.net-hidden-inputs.aspx/)
2. [ASP-NET-SEO-around-VIEWSTATE](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASP-NET-SEO-around-VIEWSTATE.aspx)
3. [hidden div elements in asp.net 4.0](https://abhijitjana.net/2010/05/18/css-friendly-menu-control-in-asp-net-4-0/)

**Update**

In your dev machine , you might have set the

```
controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"
```

so that is the reason you are unable to see that class `aspNetHidden` in your dev machine as that feature was introduced in **Asp.net 4.0**

Comment: thx, but this is not really helping. I know that ASP.net 4 introduced the class to hide the inputs and I know what it is for. What I don't get is why it is not rendered in my application when I run it with ASP.NET 4?

Comment: @spankmaster79 your dev iis version and your serve iis version? and just to confirm , you are using asp.net 4.0 and more?

Comment: dev iis version is 10, prod iis version is 8. Application Pool and framework see above

Comment: @spankmaster79 can you post you dev webconfig ?

Comment: which part. Don't want to post the whole thing. It's huge and contains sensitive information

Comment: Need `System.web and System.webserver`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126584/discussion-between-spankmaster79-and-webruster).